# Why python multiprocessing pool.join is raising a "[Errno 111] Connection refused (Python.Runtime.PythonException)"?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, connection-refused

Im very confused.... we are using multiprocessing python lib to just copy some files in parallel processes, using map.async.
Obviously i am doing something wrong, because sometimes (yes... sometimes), i´m getting a "connection refused error" when doing the pool.join.

Seems like for some reason i´m trying to join the processes but the Manager is still doing its stuff and crashes.

I would be very grateful if someone knows what can be happening.

Thank you a lot in advance!
.:ismael:.

And this is the callstack i´m getting:

```
Error: ConnectionRefusedError : [Errno 111] Connection refused (Python.Runtime.PythonException)
File "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", line 475, in generate_copy_jobs
    pool.join()
  File "/opt/custom/lib/python3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 623, in __exit__
    self.terminate()
  File "/opt/custom/lib/python3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 548, in terminate
    self._terminate()
  File "/opt/custom/lib/python3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/util.py", line 224, in __call__
    res = self._callback(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/custom/lib/python3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 581, in _terminate_pool
    cls._help_stuff_finish(inqueue, task_handler, len(pool))
  File "/opt/custom/lib/python3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 568, in _help_stuff_finish
    inqueue._reader.recv()
  File "/opt/custom/lib/python3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 251, in recv
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
  File "/opt/custom/lib/python3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 943, in RebuildProxy
    return func(token, serializer, incref=incref, **kwds)
  File "/opt/custom/lib/python3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 793, in __init__
    self._incref()
  File "/opt/custom/lib/python3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 847, in _incref
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "/opt/custom/lib/python3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 492, in Client
    c = SocketClient(address)
  File "/opt/custom/lib/python3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 620, in SocketClient
    s.connect(address)
```

Here is the snippet of the code:

```
def copyfile(data_tuple):
 
    copy_info, shared_data_dict = data_tuple
    src, dst, size, file_id = copy_info
    copy_op(src, dst)
 
    shared_data_dict[file_id] = dict(size=size, src=src, dst=dst)
 
 
manager = Manager()
shared_dict = manager.dict()
total_amount_of_data = 0
transfer_list_parameters = []
for item in transfer_list:
    total_amount_of_data += item[2]
    transfer_list_parameters.append((item, shared_dict))
total_data_mb = round(total_amount_of_data / (1024 * 1024), 2)
with Pool(processes=copy_workers) as pool:
    result = pool.map_async(copyfile, transfer_list_parameters, chunksize=chunk_size,
                            error_callback=copy_error_callback)
    while not result.ready():
        print_progress()
 
        sleep(10)
 
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: Try replacing `sleep(10)` with `result.wait(10)`.  Sleeping on the main thread can sometimes cause problems.

Comment: Why on earth do you do `pool.close()` before  `pool.join()`?  Once the pool is closed, most of the methods are unavailable.  Closing the pool closes the sockets that are used to pass data back and forth.  Swap those two lines, and I'll bet you achieve success.

Comment: Also, you really should always use an `if __name__ == "__main__": ... ` guard, even if you know you are using fork